# Rspec / Authlogic / Capybara - incorrect redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm new to testing and I'm trying to write a test in `links_spec.rb`.

```
describe "Links" do
before :each do
    activate_authlogic
    @company = Factory.build(:company)
    # next line creates errors
    @user = Factory.build(:user, :user_type => "Company", :user_type_id => @company.id)
    UserSession.create( @company.user )
end

it "redirects to index after create" do
    link = Factory.build(:link)
    post "links"
    response.should redirect_to(links_path)
end
end
```

First, the `@user = Factory.build(...)` line throws an error because it says the User is duplicated - I don't know where the user is being created because Company and User don't have a proper polymorphic relationship (that's another story), and Company.rb does not automatically create a User upon creation.

So, when I remove that line everything seems fine except when it gets to the `response.should redirect...` line. Instead of redirecting to `links_path`, the test is failing and telling me:

```
Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(links_path)
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/links> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/home>
 # ./spec/requests/links_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't understand why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: Probably a little late but can you post your factories.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to empty the database after every test?

```
# spec_helper.rb

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```